# how to find path of a node under /etc/tags in AEM?

Tags: aem

I want to search a tag under /etc/tags in AEM programmatically.
for ex:

folder structure is like 
/etc/tags/
uder tags  there are multiple tags
1.20101/ate2
2.73883
3.44qqiw
4.222

if i want  to search ate2 i should get /etc/tags/20101/ate2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QueryBuilder API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/search/querybuilder-api.html) to query it.

Sample Query would be

```
type=cq:Tag
path=/etc/tags
nodename=ate2
```

Sample SQL2 Query for the same would be

```
select * from [cq:Tag] as s where ISDESCENDANTNODE('/etc/tags') AND NAME(s)='ate2'
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is write the query as suggested by rakhi, other is to utilize `TagManager` API that provides you lot of methods to search tags and once you get `Tag` instance you could get path from it. Javadocs for `TagManager` can be found [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/tagging/TagManager.html) and for `Tag` [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/tagging/Tag.html)

For reference you could look at the code [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/tagmanager-api-search-tags.html). One thing to keep in mind in case you end up using this approach you will need to work by creating a system user to get ResourceResolver instead of calling `resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null)`, refer to article [here](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__hks9-hello_we_hav.html)